# What is the purpose of spread function in this code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, node-mysql

I am trying to figure out how to use mysql-promise. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-promise

Here is some sample code;

```
var db = require('mysql-promise')();

db.configure({
    "host": "localhost",
    "user": "foo",
    "password": "bar",
    "database": "db"
});

db.query('UPDATE foo SET key = ?', ['value']).then(function () {
    return db.query('SELECT * FROM foo');
}).spread(function (rows) { //what's purpose of spread()?
    console.log('Loook at all the foo', rows);
});
```

What is the purpose of the spread function? What exactly does it do?

Comment: mysql-promise uses bluebird ... docs for bluebird [spread](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html)

Comment: spread is being misrepresented in the context of the sample code, sort of ... there could be more than one argument available, one for each row perhaps (not sure to be honest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jaromanda X is correct, the example misrepresents [`spread`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html).

Ideal use case for spread is when your callback/ chained function expects multiple parameters, but a promise returns a single value ( our job to make sure that it is array of parameters in format used by chained function), so:

```
Promise.resolve([1,2,3]).spread(function(a, b, c){  ...
```

is equivalent to ( in ES6):

```
Promise.resolve([1,2,3]).then( ([a, b, c]) => {  ...
```

Comment: As the [docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) says, you can also do: `Promise.resolve([1,2,3]).all().then( ([a, b, c]) => {  ... })` instead of `spread(function(a, b, c){ ... })`

Answer (score 2):

`.spread` is a Bluebird (the promise library that `mysql-promise is using) function.

Basically, `.spread` allows you to handle a return value from the promise that is an array instead of a single value.

See http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The spread function comes from the Bluebird promises library that comes with the mysql-promise library. It unwraps a promise that must return an array and gives each element of that array to the function passed to it, in this case the rows from the mysql database.

From mysql-promise's package.json on github:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^2.10.2",
    "mysql": "^2.10.2"
  },
```

Here is more info from the bluebird project:
http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html